# C# custom configuration element

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I'm developing a tool which requires advanced configuration located in App/config (Web.config) file. TO achieve this I used custom configuration section.

`App.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="webConfiguration" type="MyConfigurationType, MyAssembly" />
  </configSections>

  <webConfiguration>
     <requests>
        <request name="Request-One">
            <!-- details here, but they don't matter -->
        </request>
        <request name="Request-Two" basedOn="Request-One">
            <!-- details here, but they don't matter -->
        </request>
     </requests>
  </webConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

`RequestElement.cs`

```
public class RequestElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)base["name"]; }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("basedOn", IsRequired = false)]
    public string BasedOn
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["basedOn"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["basedOn"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is pretty simple. It is compiling and working without exceptions. All I want ask, is **is it possible to create configuration property of type `RequestElement` and link it to proper one?** (like shown below)

`RequestElement.cs`

```
public class RequestElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)base["name"]; }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("basedOn", IsRequired = false)]
    public RequestElement BasedOn
    {
        get
        {
            return (RequestElement)this["basedOn"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["basedOn"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As you noticed, `Name` is a key, so using name in `App.config` file will result, that after opening `ConfigurationManager` and getting proper section, then request and any of requests, I will be able access to real object using `BasedOn` property.

Comment: You could changed on to BasedOnString and create a property that is not a configurationproperty that gets set when BasedOnString gets set? This would require you to get the parent of the ConfigurationElement and request it by name then?

Comment: How can I return proper element (with equivalent key) then? I don't have in `CustomElement` class any list which contains list of currently defined elements.

Comment: with ConfigurationElement you can get the parent, by using the `CurrentConfiguration` property, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx